# Intercept constant zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, least-squares, linear-regression

Assume that the assumptions of a classical linear regression model apply but the true value of the constant is zero, so that:

$$y=X\beta+u$$

where $X$ does not contain a column of ones in its first column.

How can I compare the expected value and variance of the least squares slope estimator computed without a constant term compared to estimator computed with constant term using the model:

$$y=\beta_{0}+X\beta+u$$

Much Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am wondering how this can be applied in general. I am not working with a specific case.